# Why moving over a <a> within a <span> counted as onmouseout?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I have created my example on here http://jsfiddle.net/Dgc5y/

What I simply want to do is when I mouseover a link, there is a popup. Then I can move over to this popup to click on more stuff and if I choose not to, it will close itself when I move out.

The problem is, when I move over the links inside this popup, it fires mouseout and closes itself.

I ended up using some hacky fix (as in the example)

I would like to know the proper way to do it, please help! Thank you!

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just using one of the many jQuery tooltip plugins out there?

Comment: Ummm, because I did not learn to work with jQuery for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers handle something showing up *under* the mouse as a mouse over.

(I've got a really neat thing involving an imagine map and a carefully placed mouse pointer can cause the whole thing to go into a flashing loop.)

I don't have a real good resolution, however.  I ended up using a semaphore in Javascript.  I set the semaphore when my popup opens, then in the `mouseover` event for the other elements, I check if the semaphore is set, and if so I bail.

Hope someone gives a better solution -- I could use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery, so you might as well move past `on*` attributes, and start writing [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). So, keeping that in mind, just use the jQuery [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event instead of the `mouseout` event.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a class="trigger" href="#" >This is what you want</a>
    <span class="tooltip" id="popup2" >
        <a href="#">ZOMG it works</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('a.trigger').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#popup2').show();
});

$('span.tooltip').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#popup2').hide();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/UwmhX

More reading: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#mouseenter

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. But jQuery is not a must, right? There gotta be some way to do it without jQuery plugin, no?

Comment: @user1589188 jQuery is _always_ a must, IMO. In all seriousness, you could do it using `onmouseleave` instead of `onmouseout`, but seriously, it's 2012. _Please_ stop using inline event handlers - think of the children!

Comment: LOL, what are you an advocate of anti-inline event handler? Anyway, thanks for the clean example

Comment: Yes, I am. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840389/why-does-jslint-restrict-the-use-of-html-event-handlers